# Taller \bowtie, \ltimes, \rtimes in pxfonts

Tags: fonts, symbols

I really like the Palatino font and its math symbols, except for one: the join symbols (`\bowtie`, `\ltimes`, `\rtimes`) are very thin.

[image]

I want them to fit neatly into a square, not into a rectangle, like this `\ltimes`:

[image]

Is there a way to either

1. stretch them,
2. import better ones from another font/package (which?),
3. define the symbol I want from scratch?

Comment: `Mnsymbol`and `mathabx` have more ‘squared’ versions of these symbols

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are similar symbols, with the same straight cuts, in the STIX fonts.

Note that using `newpxtext` and `newpxmath` rather than `pxfonts` is recommended.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{newpxtext,newpxmath}

% alias for comparison; don't use the following three lines
\let\PXbowtie\bowtie
\let\PXltimes\ltimes
\let\PXrtimes\rtimes

\let\bowtie\relax \let\ltimes\relax \let\rtimes\relax
\DeclareFontEncoding{LS1}{}{}
\DeclareFontSubstitution{LS1}{stix}{m}{n}
\DeclareSymbolFont{STIXsymbols}{LS1}{stixscr}{m}{n}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\bowtie}{\mathrel}{STIXsymbols}{"0E}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\ltimes}{\mathbin}{STIXsymbols}{"0F}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\rtimes}{\mathbin}{STIXsymbols}{"10}

\begin{document}

\makebox[3em][l]{New:} $A\bowtie B\ltimes C\rtimes D$

\makebox[3em][l]{Old:} $A\PXbowtie B\PXltimes C\PXrtimes D$

\end{document}
```

[image]